# Risk Premium Formula

Tags: self-study, risk

I was once served the formula below for calculating the risk premium in insurance. The intent is to model the risk premium in two steps, first "capping" claims larger than a certain limit, and then modelling these separately.

> Frequency*{Severity Claims + Probability for big Claim *
>   (New Big Claim model) }

So *Frequeny* and *Severity Capped Claims* are modelled with Poisson and Gamma regression and *new Big Claim model* is another distribution.

First, is this formula correct? Does not seem intuitive to me... Second, any place I can self study this exact formula?

Comment: If you are the original poster of this question and you want to delete the question, please [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts; after that you should then be able to delete it as you'll be the question owner and should see a "delete" link.